# The bound mechanism by generics for a type variable to appear in its own bound

Tags: java, object-oriented, programming-languages, polymorphism, generics

From [Programming Languages: Principles and Paradigms
By Maurizio Gabbrielli, Simone Martini](https://books.google.com/books?id=U-uBhJCRw3QC&lpg=PA321&ots=9D0lA3bvjd&pg=PA321#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> The bound mechanism for type variables is fairly sophisticated and
>   ﬂexible. In particular, a type variable can appear in its own bound.
>   We restrict ourselves to a single example of this case, and we refer
>   the reader to the bibliography for a deeper discussion.
>
> The elements of a class are comparable if the class implements the
>   `Comparable` interface.  We want to deﬁne a method which, given a list
>   of elements of generic type as its argument, returns the maximum
>   element of this list. What is the signature we can give to this max
>   method? A ﬁrst attempt is:
>
> ```
> public static <T extends Comparable<T>>
> T max(List<T> list)
> ```
>
> This expresses the fact that the elements of the list must be
>   comparable with elements of the same type. We now try to use `max`. We
>   have a type `Foo` which allows us to compare objects:
>
> ```
> class Foo implements Comparable<Object>{...}
> List<Foo> cf = ....;
> ```
>
> We now invoke `max(cf)`: each element in `cf` (is a `Foo` and
>   therefore) is comparable with any object, in particular with every
>   `Foo`. But the compiler signals an error, because `Foo` does not
>   implement `Comparable<Foo>`. In reality it is sufﬁcient that `Foo` is
>   comparable with one of its own supertypes:
>
> ```
> public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
> T max(List<T> list)
> ```
>
> Now, under the same conditions as before, `Max(cf)` is correct because
>   `Foo` implements `Comparable<Object>`.

1. I assume that `? super T` means any supertype of `T`.

   Since `Object` is a supertype of `T`, does the following signature
   of `max` work?

   ```
    public static <T extends Comparable<Object>>
    T max(List<T> list)
   ```

   If yes, why not use it instead the last one in the quote?
2. This is an **example** involving `Comparable` interface. What is the
   **general problem** that we can use the method in the quote to solve?

Answer (score 3):

If we had:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<Object>>
T max(List<T> list)
```

It would have worked with

```
class Foo implements Comparable<Object>{...}
List<Foo> cf = ....;
```

But not with

```
class Bar implements Comparable<Bar>{...}
List<Bar> cf = ....;
```

Their first `max` signature demands that `T` can be compared with `T` - therefore it can not work on a `List` of `Foo`s, because `Foo`s can be compared with `Object`. Your `max` signature demands that `T` can be compared with `Object`, therefore it can not work on a `List` of `Bar`s, because `Bar` can only be compared with another `Bar`.

Their second `max` version is needed to work on both `List<Foo>` and `List<Bar>`. It says: "*give me a list of something that can compare against other objects of it's type, but if it has a wider comparison method, that also accepts other types, that would be OK - as long as it can accept it's own type.*".

So, a list of `Baz implements Comparable<Foo>` is out of the question, because, because a `Baz` can not be compared against itself(`Baz is not a subclass of`Foo`).

Basically, the general problem solved by this method is that something in a generic may work with a subclass/superclass of the generic parameter, because you are only upcast from/to it. You use `? super T`/`? extends T` to encode this in the signature, so that the generic may be used with a wider variety of types.